# Can we Directly remove Nodes from a NodeList?

Tags: javascript

`document.getElementsByTagName` returned me a NodeList object.

I would like to remove some items (let's say I would like to remove the first item from the NodeList)

Is there a way to do it? (I'm aware that I could manually copy all the nodes into an array but I do not wish to do that if NodeList by itself already has functions for us to remove elements in it)

I am aware that removing items from a NodeList has No Effect on the display (and should not cause any browser-display-refresh or stuff like that, I simply do not wish that NodeList object to hold a referennce to that Node)

is there a way to do it? (Or am i forced to copy all the items in the NodeList into an array?)

Answer (score 30):

As you can see in the [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-536297177), there is no method to remove an element from the list.

It would not make sense anyway. This `NodeList` is **live**, meaning the DOM is searched again whenever you access a certain property, e.g. the `length`. From [MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.getElementsByTagName):

> (...) The returned list lis live, meaning that it updates itself with the DOM tree automatically. (...)

So you *have to* copy the nodes into an array.

You can do this quite easily though by using `Array` methods. E.g. to copy it and directly remove the first element:

```
var nodes = [].slice.call(elements, 1);
```

The `NodeList` is an *array-like* object. Hence we can apply array functions to it, by using [`call` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/Call). `[].slice` is just a shorthand to get a reference to the [`slice`  *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) method.

Comment: WARNING: This is an old answer. At the present, NodeList is not live always. eg. querySelectAll() returns a non-live NodeList.

Answer (score 13):

Just have the same use case as you.

For ES6 you can do this:

```
const myNodeList = ele.childNodes;

const [head, ...tail] = myNodeList;

console.log('the first item: ', head);

console.log('the remaining items: ', tail);
```

[JavaScript ES6— The Spread Syntax (…)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

Comment: Really good approach using ES6 spread. It even looks Haskell'ic (FP), so good to see that.

Answer (score -1):

```
var MySet = { 0: {value: document.body, enumerable: true}, 1: {value: document.head, enumerable: true}, 2:{value: document.documentElement, enumerable: true}, length: {value: 3}};
var protoNodelist = document.createDocumentFragment().childNodes;
var MyNodelist = Object.create(protoNodelist, MySet);
MyNodelist; // Output: NodeList {0: body, 1: head, 2: html, length: 3}
removeNode(MyNodelist, 1); // Output: NodeList {0: body, 1: html, length: 2}
    function removeNode(NodeList, i){
        var newElementSet = {};
        var newElementSeti = 0;
        for(NodeListi = 0; NodeListi < NodeList.length; NodeListi++){
            if(NodeListi != i){
                newElementSet[newElementSeti] = {value: NodeList[NodeListi], enumerable: true};
                newElementSeti += 1;
            };
        };
        newElementSet['length'] = {value: newElementSeti};
        var nodelist = document.createDocumentFragment().childNodes;
        var newNodelist = Object.create(nodelist, newElementSet);
        newNodelist.__proto__ = newNodelist.__proto__.__proto__;
        return newNodelist;
    };
```

Comment: In addition to the answer you've provided, please consider providing a brief explanation of why and how this fixes the issue.