# Does remove() remove Nodes from a Nodelist which got created by 'querySelectorAll'?

Tags: javascript

I am new to programming and have difficulties to understand following in Javascript:

My code:

```
let nodeList = document.getElementById('ID').querySelectorAll('img');
    for (i=0; i < nodeList.length; i++) {
        nodeList[i].remove();
    }
```

This code removes all referenced 'img'-elements from my HTML but no elements are removed from my 'nodeList'.

Why remove() only removes from the HTML but not remove the 'nodeList'-elements and is there a way to remove the elements from display & from the nodeList?

Thank You

Comment: It doesnt seem that NodeList has a `.remove()`

Answer (score 2):

This is because `querySelectorAll()` returns the static list of the elements. Meaning that the list will keep the reference to the element even its removed. It doesn't change after being assigned.

> The Document method `querySelectorAll()` returns a **static (not live)** NodeList representing a list of the document's elements that match the specified group of selectors

On the other hand if you want live collection you can use `document.getElementsByTagName()`,`document.getElementsByClassName()` etc

```js
const divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
divs[1].remove();
console.log(divs)
```

```html
<div>Hey</div>
<div>H</div>
<div>B</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You get your `nodeList` from nodes that are present on DOM.
Then you remove it from the DOM. If you now will run the same query - you will get a new list without these nodes.
As explained here https://stackoverflow.com/a/6545450/3125477 you can't directly remove elements from NodeList.

Answer (score -1):

Function that you are using -

```
remove()
```

Is working with DOM, and removes elements directly from there.
If you want to remove also from nodeList array - then you need to use
[splice()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp) func
The final code will looks like -

```
let nodeList = document.getElementById('ID').querySelectorAll('img');
for (i=0; i < nodeList.length; i++) {
    nodeList[i].remove();
    nodeList.splice(i,1)
}
```

Comment: [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) does not have a `splice` method. You'd have to convert it to an array first.